# Website Device Detection

Tags: php, web-deployment, device-detection

I feel like this question must have been answered here before, but I can't find it anywhere.

Can a website detect what *device* a user is browsing with? For example, if the user is browsing the website for an App, can it know to display a link to **Google Play** or **Apple App Store**, depending on what device they're using?

I don't think `$HTTP_USER_AGENT` will be enough, as an iPad user might be using [Chrome](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/mobile/ios.html), and an Android user might be using [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&hl=en), etc.

I have PHP at my disposal, as well as Javascript, naturally.

Comment: Strictly spoken technically: No. However for practical advices you should use the search ;) (I try, too)

Comment: Looked a bit around on github and came across this project: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect. Maybe you can use this.

Comment: @Tjoene That looks very smart indeed. I don't know how accurate it is, but it looks very promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to detect the device or web browser it the User Agent String, Every web browser has to provide User Agent as per the HTTP 1.1 Protocol. The User Agent String can contain multiple product tokens. By convention, the product tokens are listed in order of their significance for identifying the application.

For browsers based on Mozilla, the user-agent string shall follow the format:

```
 MozillaProductToken (MozillaComment) GeckoProductToken *
    (VendorProductToken|VendorComment)
```

Applications that embed the Gecko layout engine shall have user-agent strings that follow the format:

```
 ApplicationProductToken (ApplicationComment) GeckoProductToken *
    (VendorProductToken|VendorComment)
```

Where:

```
 ProductToken     :      Mozilla/ MozillaVersion
 Version          :      Major . Minor
 Comment          :      ( Platform; Security; OS-or-CPU;
                                 Localization information; 
                                 GeckoVersion)*[; Optional Other Comments] )
 Platform         :      Windows, Linux, Mac etc.
 Security         :      N for no security; 
                         U for strong security; 
                         I for weak security
 OS-or-CPU        :      Windows Version/MacOS 
 GeckoVersion     :      String starting with "rv:" followed 
                         by the Gecko version
 GeckoProductToken:      Gecko/GeckoDate
 GeckoDate        :      Date in the format YYYYMMDD
```

Examples

Mozilla Release

```
     Mozilla/5.001 (windows; U; NT4.0; en-US; rv:1.0) Gecko/25250101
```

A branded release based on the same codebase as the browser above

```
     Mozilla/5.001 (Macintosh; N; PPC; ja; rv:1.0) Gecko/25250101 
       MegaCorpBrowser/1.0 (MegaCorp, Inc.)
```

A re-branded release

```
      Mozilla/9.876 (X11; U; Linux 2.2.12-20 i686, en; rv:2.0) Gecko/
        25250101 Netscape/5.432b1 (C-MindSpring)
```

A Gecko-based browser

```
      TinyBrowser/2.0 (TinyBrowser Comment; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/20201231
```

## OPERA

User String Specifications:

```
  Opera/Version (OS-or-CPU; Encryption; Language)
```

## Chrome

They uses WebKit  as its rendering engine but uses a different JavaScript engine. For Chrome’s initial beta release, version 0.2, the user-agent string carries along all of the information from WebKit as well as an extra section for the Chrome version. The format is as follows:

```
  Mozilla/5.0 (Platform; Encryption; OS-or-CPU; Language) 
  AppleWebKit/AppleWebKitVersion (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/
  ChromeVersion Safari/SafariVersion

  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, 
  like Gecko) Chrome/0.2.149.29 Safari/525.13
```

## Konqueror

Konqueror, the browser bundled with the KDE Linux desktop environment, is based on the KHTML open-source rendering engine. Though available only on Linux, Konqueror has an active user base. For optimal compatibility, Konqueror opted to format its user-agent string after IE as follows:

```
 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.5; SunOS) KHTML/3.5.0 (like Gecko)
```

## WebKit

In 2003, Apple announced that it would release its own web browser, called Safari. The Safari rendering engine, called WebKit, began as a fork of the KHTML rendering engine used in the Linux-based Konqueror web browser.  But how do you ensure that the browser isn’t locked out of popular sites? The answer is, put enough information into the user-agent string to convince web sites that the browser is compatible with another popular browser. This led to a user-agent string with the following format:

```
 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/
 124 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/125.1
```

## Mobile and Tablet indicators

The platform part of the UA string indicates if Firefox is running on a phone-sized or tablet device. When Firefox runs on a device that has the phone form factor, there is a Mobile; token in the platform part of the UA string. For example:

```
 Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:13.0) Gecko/13.0 Firefox/13.0

 Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Tablet; rv:13.0) Gecko/13.0 Firefox/13.0
```

However, if you use UA sniffing to target content to a device form factor, please look for Mobi (to include Opera Mobile, which uses "Mobi") for the phone form factor and do not assume any correlation between "Android" and the device form factor.

Android

```
 Phone    :     Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:13.0) Gecko/13.0 Firefox/13.0
 Tablet   :     Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Tablet; rv:13.0) Gecko/13.0 Firefox/13.0
```

Firefox OS

```
 Phone    :     Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; rv:15.0) Gecko/15.0 Firefox/15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use both of server-side and client-side technologies to do a smart guess about which device visitor is using:

- PHP can parse the user-agent or look it up on a database of know devices
- Javascript can detect a number of APIs and features of your browser, giving you a pretty good picture about the device capabilities.

While there's no real guarantee (you're basically trusting whatever the browser is *choosing* to tell you about itself) here's two samples of what you can tell about the user device:

- http://www.thisdevice.info
- http://wwww.browserleaks.com